# How to access a shared folder with Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-directory

I have a Virtual Machine, and I want to share some files with my computer. But I don't know how to access them.

In the settings of my VM, I added the repository that I want to share. After that I started my VM and I think that I have to use the "mount" command. I also think that the repository that I want is in /dev but I don't know which file after that.

This is the command that I think I have to use :

`mount -t vfat /dev/something /media/sf-Documents`

Can someone help me and tell me how I have to do to get the content of my folder on my computer please ?

Comment: First of all: Are you using virtualbox? VmWare ? XEN?

Comment: @chrispolzer VirtualBox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, it is sufficient to:

- Install the Guest Additions
- Enter the Settings -> Shared folders menu
- Click on the "+" icon
- Select "automatic mount"
- Reboot the machine
- You'll find the shared folder under the /media directory

This procedure [is known](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12879) to not work for some versions of the Guest Additions. In case, try a different version of VirtualBox (e.g., switch from 5 to the more stable 4 version).

Comment: You're right, that's all I had to do. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

At first, to share folder between Ubuntu machines: choose folder -> right click -> folder sharing(or in file Properties). You can access files on a remote computer using SSH: Install openssh-server on a computer you want to connect to

Comment: I don't find the "Places" tab

Comment: At first, to share folder between Ubuntu machines: choose folder -> right click -> folder sharing(or in file Properties).

If your computer isn't shown in Browse Network, maybe your network isn't configured right way. then you can try the next: open nautilius, press Ctrl+L, and put smb://ip.address(change ip.address with ip of PC you wanna connect to, like smb://192.168.1.1